# Create a Docker image in command line linux from an existing directory

Tags: docker

I have a directory which contain files and subdirectories and I want to create a Docker image from this file in command line without Dockerfile for the moment, don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `docker commit`. The simplest example would look something like the following:

```
docker run -d --name my-container <base-image>
docker cp . my-container:<path-where-files-go>
docker commit my-container <new-image-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer surely works but is prone to producing inconsistent images. I would recommend using a [`dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). This gives you a single point to make changes to your images. See example below...

Assuming your working directory has a single folder `foo` which you need in your `image` So next to it, create a file named `dockerfile` then edit the file to look as below

```
FROM <your_base_image:latest>
COPY foo /path/of/folder/in/image/foo
```

Now run the command below in your `terminal`. Ensure your working directory has both `dockerfile` and the folder `foo`

```
docker build . -t <your_image_name>
```

This `dockerfile` can be used to generate the exact same image every other time. Any changes added to it means that all new images generated from that `dockerfile` will contain the changes. Below are other commands you can add in your `dockerfile` to enrich the resulting `images` with `nano` editor

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano -y
```

Comment: How can I do if the folder I want to copy is out of the Dockerfile folder ?

Comment: @Stecko48 you can either move it so that they sit together in the same folder, or copy it to where your `dockefile` is if moving is not an option. Then run the `docker build` command in that directory